# Animation when transition between tabs in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ionic 2 app with basic tabs.

```
<ion-tabs selectedIndex="1">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="hunts" tabIcon="book"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="hunting" tabIcon="locate"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

The tabs appears perfectly. But I would like to have a sliding animation when transitioning between tabs. That is, when I press the rightmost tab from the middle tab, middle tab should slide to left and rightmost tab should slide in from right. This is a basic android animation.

I am unable to find any details on how to accomplish this. Is this still not possible in Ionic (2.2.0) ?

Comment: Well, in short ionic team has not developed this yet. Check out this issue: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5101

Comment: I do not want swiping as mentioned in the issue. Just animate when in transition.

Comment: Well, I checked and ionic has only 3 types of transitions for pages. ios-transition, md-transition and wp-transition. Not really direction https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/

Comment: Guess its still a work in progress. Anyway Thanks misha for the help.

Comment: Hey! Don't forget to mark your issue as resolved ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Before starting**

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/native-page-transitions
```

Then **import the plugin** in your **`src/app/app.module.ts`** the following way

```
import { NativePageTransitions } from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions';
```

And **add it as a provider**.

```
  providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    NativePageTransitions // <-- add me here
  ]
```

**Go to your `src/pages/tabs/tabs.ts`**

**Import the plugin**

```
import { NativePageTransitions, NativeTransitionOptions } from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions';
```

**Add the plugin to the constructor**

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              private nativePageTransitions: NativePageTransitions) {
  }
```

**Add these 2 variables**

```
loaded:   boolean = false;
tabIndex: number  = 0;
```

**Then add these two functions**

```
  private getAnimationDirection(index:number):string {
    var currentIndex = this.tabIndex;

    this.tabIndex = index;

    switch (true){
      case (currentIndex < index):
        return('left');
      case (currentIndex > index):
        return('right');
    }
  }

  public transition(e:any):void {    
    let options: NativeTransitionOptions = {
     direction:this.getAnimationDirection(e.index),
     duration: 250,
     slowdownfactor: -1,
     slidePixels: 0,
     iosdelay: 20,
     androiddelay: 0,
     fixedPixelsTop: 0,
     fixedPixelsBottom: 48
    };

    if (!this.loaded) {
      this.loaded = true;
      return;
    }

    this.nativePageTransitions.slide(options);
  }
```

**Then go to `src/pages/tabs/tabs.html`**
Modify the ion-tabs tag the following way :

```
<ion-tabs (ionChange)="transition($event)">
```

or

```
<ion-tabs (ionSelect)="transition($event)">
```

**Edit for Ionic 4**

`<ion-tabs (ionTabsWillChange)="transition($event)">`

Enjoy.

PS: You can find the full code on my gist [glemiere/58d1707ba82d40a55967601dbd0e72c9](https://gist.github.com/glemiere/58d1707ba82d40a55967601dbd0e72c9).

**EDIT**
If you want to modify the animation, here are the all the informations you need.
http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/native-page-transitions

Comment: I was looking for a Ionic implementation rather than a native plugin. But apparently due to difficulty in implementation and low priority, this is still in feature request. There are some custom ionic components out there as well.

Comment: Well then I guess you can mix my code with an angular animation :
https://angular.io/guide/animations

Comment: I guess ionChange event doesn't work anymore. I had to replace it with ionSelect in my case.

Comment: @negative_zero which version of ionic are you using ? It should be specified in your package.json

Comment: @GuillaumeLeMière 3.9.2

Comment: It does work on my setup, that's weird U_U
Well thank you to give this extra information if anybody else gets the same issue ^_^

Comment: What's the use of the `loaded:boolean` variable ?

Comment: It does prevent the animation from firing when the app launches

Comment: actually works with `<ion-tabs (ionTabsWillChange)="transition($event)">`

Answer (score 17):

I came up just now with e diffrent solution ... hehe
It's a funny one, a primitive idea but it gives you half of transition feeling in 2 minutes

**Pure CSS:**

1. In a **global app's scss** file make a css selector that will grab components loaded into router outlet of your **< ion-tabs >**
2. **Add an css animation** on start :P - it will be run every time a new component is inserted

```css
app-e-tabs ion-router-outlet > .ion-page { 
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s 1 forwards;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 5vh, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Of course there are probobly thousends of possible problems and it will never look like the proper page transition .. but it's better then nothing :)

EDIT:
As some people pointed out you should remove `app-e-tabs` from first line of css - it is the name of a module in my app - that's why it landed in my code.

Comment: Great solution! I had to remove `app-e-tabs` to make it work. This solution deserves more credit. :-)

Comment: Removing "app-e-tabs" and just paste above code in "global.scss"  works brilliant!

Comment: Good alternative, for a lot of cases this should be sufficient.

Comment: Hahah great job man!