# How to animate ion-tabs transition between tabs? ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework

I tried to do it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44774422/9899330), but it doesn't work for me. Also console give's me a message that "StatusBar is not supported".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animation when transition between tabs in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858415/animation-when-transition-between-tabs-in-ionic-2)